# AJAX Response .NET 3.5 or 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

What controls the version of ASP.NET that is used during an AJAX request? I have an issue where on a local environment the response is contained in “.d” while on a different environment the response is not in “.d.”

Having read http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/ I know a possible solution and I am assuming that the difference between environments is the ASP.NET version being run. Instead of implementing the datafilter fix I'd like to know what I should be changing on the environment to have the response be in ".d" I checked the web.config and see that it does say 3.5 as the version for
System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0.

What should I be checking?

Answer (score 0):

The version of `System.Web.Extensions` should be responsible for that. Both the HttpModule that handles WebMethods in ASPX pages and the HttpHandler that augments ASMX services with the same functionality use `System.Web.Extensions`.

Check the references in the project. If the older version of the assembly is referenced, it could still pull that from the GAC even if 3.5 is mentioned in the web.config.

You might also try using [bindingRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) force the older version not to be used.

Comment: But if the version being referenced was the issue then why would it act as ASP.NET 3.5 on one environment and not the other?

Comment: I think that discrepancy could arise if you had one GAC with the old ASP.NET Extensions 1.0 installed (the ASP.NET 2.0 ASP.NET AJAX) and one without. It would make sense for a server to have it installed over time or to support older apps, but a developer's workstation to not have it installed.